# Recursive C void function and return keyword

Tags: c, recursion, return, void

Does someone know the internal differences between :

```
void RecFoo1(int bar){
  if (bar == 0)
    return ;
  RecFoo1(bar - 1);
}
```

and

```
void RecFoo2(int bar){
  if (bar == 0)
    return ;
  return RecFoo2(bar - 1);
}
```

I am convinced that it is always better to put the return keyword. If the recursive function is not a void function, one will get a warning from `-Wreturn-type`. But are these two piece of code compiled/executed the same way or not ? What are the internal differences for the machine ?

My example of function is stupid but it constitute a kind of minimal example...

Comment: One is legal C and the other is not. You cannot return a void expression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The C standard is quite clear on this, your RecFoo2 example is not a valid C program:

> 6.3.2.2 void
>
> The (nonexistent) value of a void expression (an expression that has
>   type void) shall not be used in any way, ...

and

> 6.8.6.4 The return statement
>
> > Constraints
>
> A return statement with an expression shall not appear in a function
>   whose return type is void.

Comment: Thanks, it is clear as the ISO C says : don't do that... I wonder anyway how a such code is treated...

Comment: @user3005788 it works as described (i.e. no difference) on all compilers i've seen. However, standard discourages that.

Answer (score 4):

In a `void` function, `return` is simply a control-flow operation - exit the current function. You could add one in the last line of the function:

```
void RecFoo1(int bar){
  if (bar == 0)
    return ;
  RecFoo(bar - 1);
  return; // Unnecessary!
}
```

But it's completely redundant.

Your second query won't compile - you can't return a value in a void function.

Comment: Since the function called is of return type `void`, is he actually returning a *value*? (Just pulling your leg there. ;-) )

Comment: Actually, RecFoo2 compile without warning with `-Wall -ansi` but `-pedantic` says :  warning: ISO C forbids ‘return’ with expression, in function returning void [-Wpedantic]

Answer (score 2):

There is no real difference. Actually I expected to get no difference at all, but look at this.

Compare of generated assembly code without optimizations (got it by passing `-save-temps` option to gcc):

```
diff --git a/without-expr.s b/with-expr.s
index a7577f5..e346d6f 100644
--- a/without-expr.s
+++ b/with-expr.s
@@ -18,6 +18,7 @@ L2:
        decl    %eax
        movl    %eax, (%esp)
        call    _RecFoo2
+       nop
        jmp     L1
 L4:
        nop
```

With optimizations generated code is exactly the same (I tried `-O2`).

So without optimizations compiler generates an extra `nop` for `return` with an expression, but it's not something you should really care about.