# Does returning to another void function from a void function is legal in C++?

Tags: c++, recursion

The C standard [prohibit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22376051/recursive-c-void-function-and-return-keyword) this. But I'm not sure what C++ standard says about this.

```
#include <iostream>

void bar() {
    std::cout << "From Bar" << "\n";
}

void foo() {
    std::cout << "From Foo" << "\n";
    
    return bar();
}

int main()
{
    foo();
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program compiles and works just fine. I like the style of `return bar();` instead `bar(); return;`

Is this legal in C++11?

The answer below mentions that it's legal on latest draft.

Comment: Just a statement `bar();` and a `return;` after that should be sufficient. I'd not call that _recursion_ btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is allowed in C++. The standard says (quote from latest draft):

> [stmt.return]
>
> ... A return statement with an operand of type void shall be used only in a function whose return type is cv void. ...

Comment: Does that draft applies to C++11 or C++20 (or future)?

Comment: @jeffbRTC The current draft potentially applies to future. You can check the older drafts to see if the rule has changed over time.

Comment: Any links where to find the older drafts?

Comment: A similar statement exists in all ratified C++ standards to date, although there are minor changes of wording.   For example, C++98, Section 6.3.3 [stmt.return], para 3. states."A return statement with an expression of type “*cv* `void`” can be used only in functions with a return type of *cv* `void`; the expression is evaluated just before the function returns to its caller."